# Login using Google+ on a Django Site

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-templates, django-views, google-plus

Hi everyone I want to put a google+ login button on my website (coded in django) w/o using any 3rd party tool like Django-Social-Auth, etc.

So can anyone point me to some tutorial or help me how to do it. I want user to login via Google+ and then I can get their information at backend in django﻿ views. I will be then hosting it on Google App Engine so if some GAE API can help me then it will also be great.

Comment: Are you trying to do this: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution:

1. Got access_token using https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow
2. Then send out the access_token to Server for getting User Details, considering these security measures (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/client-to-server-flow).
3. Use Django CSRF Token functionality to send token safely (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/).